# Reading XML data between tags

Tags: java, xml, servlets, jdom

I have a XML for which i am writing a servlet to pick up contents from the XML. One such tag is `<itunes:author>Jonathan Kendrick</itunes:author>`
I need to get author value for this. because of **:**

I tried using namespace and using escape sequence for **:** but it did not worked for me.

For rest of other XML elements i am simply using

```
String link=node.getChildText("link").toString();
```

I am using Jdom parser

Comment: You should be able to get this using the overload of getChildText that takes a namespace.  Can you elaborate more on how that failed?

Comment: it did not provided me any value in the desired container. Can you provide an example for the same. Thanks

Comment: I might have tried for an example, but now rolfi has in his answer, which looks right to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your XML the sequernce 'itunes:author' represents what's called a Q-Namem a "Qualified Name". In XML it consists of a 'Namespace prefix', and a 'Local Name'. In your example, the namespace prefix is 'itunes', and the 'local name' is 'author'.

What you want is the 'author' element in the namespace linked to the prefix 'itunes'. The actual namespace is normally a full URL. I believe the full URL for your example is probably xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd", but you should check that.

So, the Namespace is "http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd", it's prefix is declared to be 'itunes' (but it could be something else - the actual prefix name is not technically important...)

You want to get the 'author' in the 'http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd' Namespace so you want:

```
String author = node.getChildText("author", Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd"));
```

For more information on Namespaces check out: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

Comment: Getting error while compilation : cannot resolve symbol
symbol  : variable Namespace

Comment: imported import org.jdom.Namespace; for the same. Issue resolved. Thanks